# Threads in django application

Tags: python, django, apache

I am using threading for socket connection to another machine in my django application hosted on apache mpm worker. the problem is apache creates many processes and django creates that many threads.

Basically i want it to make only one thread even if apache creates many processes.

is there any way i can stop django from making many threads.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using WSGI to do this. In the [configuration guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) there is a bit about

```
WSGIDaemonProcess example.com processes=2 threads=15
```

that may come in useful.

Answer (score 0):

For Django will be better to use WSGI(gunicorn/uwsgi) and nginx web server as frontend.

Try this http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/

If you still wants to use apache + django through fastcgi, you can try to set FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass(DefaultMaxClassProcessCount), FcgidMinProcessesPerClass(DefaultMinClassProcessCount), FcgidMaxProcesses(MaxProcessCount), FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess( MaxRequestsPerProcess) to 1 - mod_fcgid(apache2). I don't know how works mod_python, but I think It's not good idea to use it.